# Unable to send messages form Wagtail form using gmail

Tags: django, email, wagtail

I'm trying to use my Gmail account to receive messages form my Wagtail/Django app. The messagesget added to Forms in admin panel and get printed in the console, however, they do not get send to and from my gmail account.
My settings ass below:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'mg@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'Password$'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL ='noreply@mysite.com'
EMAIL_TO = 'mg@gmail.com'
```

I tried to overwrite sent_mail function in ContactForm(AbstractEmailForm) and replace from_address and to_address with DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL and EMAIL_TO. No success.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I have experienced is you may want to check and allow the **"less secure app"** setting in your google account setting.

Answer (score 0):

please check your email settings in smtp provider's dashboard

Comment: if you're hosting email server on same App server/os then you should do your researches about how to create your Email server (SMTP)